# Secure coding of Set<CustomObject>

Tags: swift, core-data, transformable, nssecurecoding

My app uses core data, which stores instances of a custom class `CustomClass`.
This class has a number of properties, most of them of standard types, but one property is `xxx: Set<CustomObject>`.
The `xcdatamodeld` thus specifies (among the others with standard types) an attribute `xxx` of type `Transformable`. `xxx` is the `Set<CustomObject>`.
Its type is `Optional` and the Transformer is now `NSSecureUnarchiveFromData`.
Earlier the Transformer was not specified, and thus decoding was not secure. But Apple now advises to use secure coding, since insecure coding will be deprecated in future.

To enable secure coding, I did the following:
`CustomClass` now adopts `NSSecureCoding` instead of `NSCoding`.
The following `var` was added to `CustomClass`:

```
public static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool { get { return true } }
```

Then I tried to modify `public required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {…}` so that attribute `xxx` is securely decoded. I know that instead of

```
let xxx = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: „xxx“) as? Set<CustomObject>
```

I have to use now `decodeObject(of:forKey:)`, where `of` is the type of the object to be decoded, here type `Set<CustomObject>`.
My problem is that I don’t know how to formulate this: If I use

```
let xxx = aDecoder.decodeObject(of: Set<CustomObject>.self, forKey: „xxx“)
```

I get the error `Cannot convert value of type 'Set<CustomObject>.Type' to expected argument type '[AnyClass]?' (aka 'Optional<Array<AnyObject.Type>>‘)`.
Apparently the compiler did not compile

```
func decodeObject<DecodedObjectType>(of cls: DecodedObjectType.Type, forKey key: String) -> DecodedObjectType? where DecodedObjectType : NSObject, DecodedObjectType : NSCoding
```

but instead

```
func decodeObject(of classes: [AnyClass]?, forKey key: String) -> Any?
```

i.e. it treated `Set<CustomObject>` not as a single type, but as a collection of types.

So, how do I specify that only a single type should be decoded, namely `Set<CustomObject>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I could not find anything in the Apple docs, but I found a hint to the solution in [this post](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6733-nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-permanently-save-app-data):
`NSSecureCoding` is **not available** for all standard swift classes. For those classes, that don’t support it, one has to use the Objective-C counterpart classes, i.e. `NSString` instead of `String`.

One example: If `var string = "String"` has to be securely encoded, one has to use e.g. `aCoder.encode(string as NSString, forKey: „string“)`.

Now currently `Set` is not supported by `NSSecureCoding`. I had to use thus

```
let aSet: Set<CustomObject> = []
aCoder.encode(aSet as NSSet, forKey: „aSet“)
```

and

```
let decodedSet = aDecoder.decodeObject(of: NSSet.self, forKey: „aSet“) as? Set<CustomObject>
```